# Deploying an Azure Web App with maven

Tags: java, maven, azure

I am currently developing an Azure web application(using their Paas service) in Java and would like to deploy to the app using maven as part of our continuous integration pipeline but cannot find any plugins to do this.  Are there any if so where can I find them?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use git push to sync your code to github and setup continuous deployment from github to Azure Web Application. Maven has a git plugin to do a git push onto github.

Answer (score 0):

You can use upload goal from [maven-wagon-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/) as described by Steven Engelhardt in his [blogpost](https://stevenengelhardt.com/2014/05/01/publishing-a-java-servlet-to-azure-website-using-maven/).

The wagon-ftp extension of the plugin allows to transfer your war file by ftp to /site/wwwroot/webapps folder on azure Web app. That will redeploy the application.

Comment: A short summary would help reviewers (like me) to judge the validity of your answer, and may save some readers from following that link. Just a sentence or two would be fine and not too much work.